# Database.executeBatch cannot be called from a batch start, batch execute, or future method

Tags: trigger, exception

I have an `after insert,after update` trigger on object A which calls Database.executeBatch for insert and update operation which inserts and updates object A records.I have another`after insert` trigger on object B which also performs DML operation for object A records.But I am getting this exception.

`Database.executeBatch cannot be called from a batch start, batch execute, or future method.`

Is there any work around for this so that I can bypass the trigger?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: hope this helps
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44040/is-using-database-executebatch-from-a-trigger-an-anti-pattern

Answer (score 1):

Therefore often Trigger Architecture Frameworks are used.

The fundamental principles are:

- Order of execution
- Separation of concerns
- **Control over reentrant code**
- Clear organization and structure

I would recommend to start reading here [Generic Apex Trigger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17527/generic-apex-trigger/17529#17529) and go on with the links provided in the answer of Andrew Fawcett.