# Trigger error - Too many DML rows: 10001

Tags: apex, trigger, governorlimits, dml

I have tried to optimize the code, but still it throws the error:

```
Too many DML rows: 10001
```

Below is my code:

```
if(setAccID != null && !setAccID.isEmpty())
      {
        list<Custom__c> lst = [select id, MyAcc_Id__c from Custom__c where MyAcc_Id__c in:setAccountID];
      {
         if(lst != null && !lst.isEmpty())
         {
           for(Custom__c objCustom : lst)
           {
                objCustom.Date_Time__c = system.now();
                objCustom.Code__c = 'C';              
           }
           update lst;

          }
         }
       }
     }
```

Sometimes, I get the error and not always.
I have removed the  `update lst;` out of the for loop.

I read in developer forums and some posts that we need to pass data in batch or write a batch job but I am not sure how to achieve this.

Please suggest!

Comment: Batch job may be the best approach in case if you need to update a lot of records. Please, check following module https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/asynchronous_apex/units/async_apex_batch for nice tutorial about it

Comment: Can you please suggest how to call a batch job from my trigger code?

Answer (score 3):

When you get such errors you need to read them carefully; this one is talking about the number of *rows* not the *number of DML statements*. While nominally the problem could be addressed by starting a batchable from the trigger, be aware of [Is using Database.executeBatch from a trigger an anti-pattern?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44040/is-using-database-executebatch-from-a-trigger-an-anti-pattern).

Best you take a step back and re-examine the requirement: what is the code aiming to do? Starting from that you may be able to construct a solution that doesn't suffer from this problem.

Answer (score 1):

> System.LimitException: Too many DML rows: 10001 error occurs when we
>   try to do DML operations to more than 10000 records at a time.

If we want to do DML operations to more than 10000 records at a time, we have to call a batch class from the current class to handle it separately.

You can learn the basics of batch class here:-

1. [Use Batch Apex](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/asynchronous_apex/units/async_apex_batch)
2. [Using Batch Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm)
3. [How to execute Batch Apex Using Apex Trigger?](http://sfdcsrini.blogspot.com/2014/06/how-to-execute-batch-apex-using-apex.html)

If you want to avoid, You can optimize based on do you really need to update all the list rows without checking any condition.